# Retornar arreglo de datos en respuesta de PHP

Tags: php

Hola quisiera que mi respuesta retorne de forma correcta, les adjunto mi código y la explicación

```
public function getVentasNetasById($codigo_vendedor) {
    $response = array();
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * from ventas_netas 
    where slpcode = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $codigo_vendedor);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      $response = array(
         'id' => $row['id'],
          'ventas_netas' => utf8_encode($row['line_total']),
       );
      return $response;
    } else return RECORD_DOES_NOT_EXIST;
}
```

Obtengo como resultado esto: `"cventas": {"id": 194, "ventas_netas": "1163.03"}`
pero el campo `splcode` tiene 3 valores mas, es decir me debe retornar 4 arreglos según el campo `splcode`, pero el problema es que siempre me devuelve solo un arreglo. Quisiera algo como esto:

```
{
    "id": 194,
    "ventas_netas": "1163.03"
}, {
    "id": 194,
    "ventas_netas": "36.03"
}, {
    "id": 194,
    "ventas_netas": "85.03"
}, {
    "id": 194,
    "ventas_netas": "63.03"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberías recorrer el resultado en un ciclo e ir almacenándolo en una variable de tipo array, te dejo un ejemplo.

```
 $result = $this->db->get();

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            $data = $result->result_array();
            $result_data = array();

            foreach($data as $data_email){
                $result = array(
                    'date_init_send' => $data_email['date_sent'],
                    'email_from' => $data_email['from_addr'],
                    'email_to' => $data_email['to_addrs'],
                    'content_email' => $data_email['description_html'],
                    'attached_id' => $data_email['attached_id'],
                    'path' => $data_email['path'],
                    'filename' => $data_email['filename'],
                    'document_name' => $data_email['document_name'],
                    'description' => $data_email['description'],
                    'file_mime_type' => $data_email['file_mime_type'],
                );

                $result_data[] = $result;
            }
            return $result_data;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

También tienes esta alternativa:

```
public function getVentasNetasById($codigo_vendedor) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, line_total as ventas_netas
    FROM ventas_netas 
    WHERE slpcode = :search");

    $stmt->bindValue(':search', $codigo_vendedor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($result) {

        return $result;
    } else {

        return RECORD_DOES_NOT_EXIST;
    }
}
```

Esto tendrá el mismo efecto que lo que tratas de hacer, avisa si te fue útil por favor.